# InvalidCastException in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, exception

For this LINQ query I'm getting the exception below:

```
(from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
 where row.Field<string>("Dept_line_code") == DeptCode &&
 row.Field<string>("Skill_Name") == skill &&
 row.Field<string>("Acct_Code") == account && row.Field<string>("Location") == dtNewTable.Rows[intRow]["Location"].ToString()
 select row.Field<int>("Presently_Available") == null ? 0 : row.Field<int>("Presently_Available")
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Exception information:

> Exception type: InvalidCastException
>
> Exception message: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.

I don't know nullable type and I'm not getting how to use nullable type to overcome this exception.

Comment: Briefly: by default, primitive types (such as `int`, `double`, `float`, ...) can't be assigned null values. The solution to this problem is to use a nullable type instead (like `int?`), which is really just a wrapper around the primitive type.

Comment: Seems that you use DataSet, probably filled by DataAdapter. Then you can fill not a DataSet [but a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx), if you're sure that resulting query contains only the single table.

Comment: When we need to use nullable types? what scenarios? why we have to use the same? Need information about the purpose and Pros or Cons with NUllable types?

Comment: @sukumar Google "nullable types C#" and read about it. You need to learn how to research your own issues rather than asking people to give you answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you have to make int accept null value => int?

```
row.Field<int?>("Presently_Available") == null ? 0 : row.Field<int>("Presently_Available") ;
```

and this is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the Nullable Types

Comment: You should probably give a link or a brief explanation of nullable types in your answer. The OP isn't going to understand why `int?` fixes his problem.

Comment: Wow, a couple hours of searching to find out I just needed a question mark!

Answer (score 9):

```
select row.Field<int?>("Presently_Available")
```

Answer (score 7):

change  `row.Field<int>` to  `row.Field<int?>`